# Can cherrypick all PR(pull request) from github?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

Is it possible to cherry-pick all pending PR from github?

Let's say I have 4 PR from 4 different forked repositories waiting for review.  I need to apply all of them to the latest source code.

```
PR#65 Do something
PR#61 Notify this
PR#55 Fix that
PR#42 Show there
```

I know that I can `git remote add` all repositories and cherry-pick them one by one.  However, I believe there would be easier/shorter way to **cherry-pick all pending pull request** which I don't know yet ;)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think that a PR in GitHub (or any other Git repo provider) can have more than a single repo/branch destination.  It sounds like your workflow is a mess, from what I read above.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, How can I improve my workflow? Please guide me

Comment: Why do you have so many forked respositories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### in short:

add pr/* to .git/config

---

### in detail:

#### Assume the repository is named `test_repo`

```
$ git remote -v
test_repo     http://github/testA.git (fetch)
test_repo     http://github/testA.git (push)
```

#### 1. open git config

```
vim .git/config
```

#### 2. add below line under `[remote "test_repo"]`

```
fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/test_repo/pr/*
```

so it would look like

```
[remote "test_repo"]
url = http://github/testA.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/test_repo/*
fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/test_repo/pr/*  <-- this line was added
```

#### 3. "git fetch" will fetch PRs too

```
$ git fetch test_repo

 * [new ref]         refs/pull/16/head -> test_repo/pr/16
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/17/head -> test_repo/pr/17
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/18/head -> test_repo/pr/18
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/19/head -> test_repo/pr/19
```

#### 4. now you can cherry-pick/checkout to PR #xx

```
git cherry-pick test_repo/pr/xx
```

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something with this. This didn't cherry-pick all the commits in the PR but just the last commit.

Answer (score 4):

You can't cherrypick the commits because the commits are not in your local repository.

You should fetch the pull requests like that..

1 by 1:
https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/

All at once:
https://gist.github.com/piscisaureus/3342247

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is `pull` each `PR-branch` one-by-one, resolve conflicts as required.

Given:

```
  - PR#65 at https://github.com/author_1/your-repo/tree/PR-branch-name-1
  - PR#61 at https://github.com/author_2/your-repo/tree/PR-branch-name-2
  - PR#55 at https://github.com/author_3/your-repo/tree/PR-branch-name-3
  - PR#42 at https://github.com/author_4/your-repo/tree/PR-branch-name-4
```

then pull each PR locally:
e.g. the `PR#65`:

```
git checkout <your-test-branch>
git pull https://github.com/author_1/your-repo.git PR-branch-name-1
```

Comment: Use `git fetch`, not `git pull`, here, as `git pull` will `git merge` the pull request commit but the goal is to *cherry pick* rather than merging. (In general I commend not using `git pull` at all.)

Comment: That technically true @torek. But since the OP is looking for easier/shorter way to have the PR commit(s) within the source code, `git pull` is the way to go as it will `fetch` the PR branch and `merge` all the commits in the PR in one go.

Comment: That's the thing: he said, rather clearly, that he did not *want* them *merged.*